# How to use Springy.js in an Angular application?

Tags: angular, springy.js

I want to use [Springy.js](https://github.com/dhotson/springy) in an Angular application.

I added the library with `npm install springy --save` and created this simple test:

```
import {Springy} from 'springy';

...

calculate() {
    const graph = new Springy.Graph();
    ... 
}
```

but I get

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Graph' of undefined

So the Springy library seems not to be packed?

I can see the springy library in my node_modules.
I also restarted my Angular serve process.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dennis Hotson I have got the solution.

I need to use

```
import Springy from 'springy';
```

instead of

```
import {Springy} from 'springy';
```

So without the braces.

Comment: I get this when I try that: `error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'springy'. '.../node_modules/springy/springy.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`